# Proving spanning trees contain all pendant edges.

Tags: graph-theory

Illustrate and prove that each spanning tree of a connected graph G contains all the pendant edges of G.

I already know how to illustrate, however can't prove. It says I need to use contradiction. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Take some vertex $x$ that has only one neighbor $y$ in $G$, and let $T$ be a spanning tree of $G$.  Recall that $V(T) = V(G)$ and $E(T) \subseteq E(G)$, by definition.  In particular, $x \in V(T)$.

Suppose now that the edge $xy$ does not belong to $T$.  Since $T$ is connected, $x$ must have at least one neighbor $w$ on $T$, and so $xw \in E(T)$.

Can you finish the rest?